# Entry Form: redirect not working

Tags: form, redirect, saveentry

I use a front-end entry form based on the official documentation (https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/entry-form), but after saving the entry, I am running in an error 404 on the entry page.

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="viewentry/{id}">
```

But if I replace the entry id with the slug in the browser (example.com/viewentry/example), then it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing `{id}` with `{slug}`. I guess it needs a slug, not an ID.

Comment: You're right - and the docs probably wrong. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad I could help :)